# How I can split string by comma and/or new line and/or whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi there I am searching for regex to split emails, but no success so far.
What is the point
I  want to make possible to separate this:

```
o@gmail.com b@gmail.com c@gmail.om
```

or

```
o@gmail.com, b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com
```

or

```
o@gmail.com,
 b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: when you do the string .split, use this regex: /\s+|,/g (it will search for spaces, or comma, or tabs, or new lines, or returns). ex: console.log(s.split(/\s+|,/g))

Comment: @Celsiuss, no, I am searching more on how to separate lines here, because of dealing with multiple emails

Comment: How does that not answer it? Use regex, execute it on your string, iterate over the matches and you got your emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split on either a comma surrounded by some number of white-space characters, or just one or more white-space characters:

```js
let strs = ['o@gmail.com b@gmail.com c@gmail.om',
'o@gmail.com, b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com',
'o@gmail.com,\n\
 b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com'];

console.log(strs.map(s => s.split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You regex should be `,\s*|\s+`:

- first part `,\s*` takes anything with comma followed by 0 or more whitespaces (whitespace is defined as \n, \r, \t, \f, or " "), so e.g. space + new line + space
- second part `\s+` takes one or more whitespaces (without coma).

Example:

```
var emails = `o@gmail.com b@gmail.com,o@gmail.com,
 b@gmail.com, c@gmail.com
o@gmail.com b@gmail.com`

test.split(/,\s*|\s+/); // <- splits to 7 emails
```